# Mobile Safari: detect tab key press in contenteditable field

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

On my PhoneGap / cordova app, I've noticed that keydown / keypress events are not being fired when the user clicks the TAB button on iOS.

After doing some more testing, it looks like the keydown event doesn't even get fired in mobile Safari when the TAB key is pressed: http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html.

Is there no way to detect if the TAB key is pressed in an edit field for mobile Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works on script I've created for Mobile Safari (https://github.com/zvona/Servant.js).

See example at (I tested with iOS 8.1.3 and it worked): http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/vNyvdV

Example code:

```
document.addEventListener('nextbuttonclick', function() {
  console.log('next');
}, false);

document.addEventListener('previousbuttonclick', function() {
  console.log('prev');
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had been contemplating doing something similar -- checking the tab index of the previously selected item to see if it was adjacent to the current selection in the focus() event. Looks like you're ahead of me! :-)